# Laravel 10 updating child records with dynamic input fields

Tags: mysql, eloquent, laravel-10

I want to update child records but it's updating the records with last element in an array. Records to update:

```
array:2 [ // app\Http\Controllers\VariantController.php:134
  "name" => "Size"
  "values" => array:3 [
     0 => "S"
     1 => "M"
     2 => "L"
  ]
]
```

My update method code:

```
$variant = Variant::findorFail($id);

DB::transaction(function () use ($request, $variant) {
    $variant->update([
        'name' => $request['name']
    ]);

    foreach ($request['values'] as $value) {
        $variant->variant_values->update([
            'value' => $value
        ]);
    }
});
```

The above code is working fine for create but not working for update.

My Variant Model Code:

```
protected $fillable = ['name'];

public function variant_values()
{
    return $this->hasMany(VariantValue::class);
}
```

My VariantValue Model Code:

```
protected $fillable = ['value'];

public function variant()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Variant::class);
}
```

My goal is to update the variant_values.However, user can add more or update existing value.